# How to print NEW value with trigger Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I want to create trigger for Insert operation, and procedure that prints inserted value.

```
CREATE TRIGGER added_product_info_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON products
EXECUTE PROCEDURE added_product_info();
```

And my procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION added_product_info()
RETURNS trigger
AS
$$
    (Select p.productname, s.companyname from products as p, suppliers as s
    where p.supplierid = s.supplierid)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

How can I print my inserted value?

Comment: `raise notice`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE

Answer (score 5):

Sql functions cannot return `trigger`. You probably wanted to write a plpgsql function.

A trigger function cannot generate any output (like results of a `select` query). 
You can use `raise notice` to pass some results to the client program:

```
create or replace function added_product_info()
returns trigger as $$
declare 
    company text;
begin
    select companyname 
    from suppliers
    where supplierid = new.supplierid
    into company;
    raise notice 'inserted: "%" supplied by "%"', new.productname, company;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The record `new` is visible in a trigger function only if the trigger is declared `for each row` 
(default is `for each statement` when records `new` and `old` are not accessible):

```
create trigger added_product_info_trigger
before insert on products
for each row
execute procedure added_product_info();
```

If a trigger is `before insert for each row` it must return `new`.

Note that the client must be ready to get and process the notice.
If you run the query in the standard **psql** shell program, you ll get:

```
insert into products values ('some product', 1);
NOTICE:  inserted: "some product" supplied by "company"
INSERT 0 1
```

Read:

- [Overview of Trigger Behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/trigger-definition.html)
- [Visibility of Data Changes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/trigger-datachanges.html)
- [Trigger Procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)